# Decimal not showing group(thousand) separator after parse

Tags: c#, decimal, globalization, cultureinfo, culture

In console application I've created 2 decimals:

1. using literal value
2. using a string parse

I've set my culture to "en-GB"

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB");
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB");

Decimal money = 14343431.948M;
Decimal moneyConversion = decimal.Parse("-34,555.897"); 

string decimalString = money.ToString("N3");
string moneyConversionString = moneyConversion.ToString("N3");

Console.WriteLine("Decimal value: " + decimalString); //prints 14,343,431.948
Console.WriteLine("Decimal value Converted: " + moneyConversion); //-34555.897
```

The first writeline shows the decimal representation as expected while the second prints **-34555.897** but I was expecting **-34,555.897**, I'm missing the comma that separates the thousands. How come?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
Console.WriteLine("Decimal value Converted: " + moneyConversion); //-34555.897
```

You're using `moneyConversion` (the `decimal` value) rather than `moneyConversionString`. If you change it to:

```
Console.WriteLine("Decimal value Converted: " + moneyConversionString);
```

you'll get the formatting you expect. Otherwise you're just effectively calling `moneyConversion.ToString()` which will use the default "G" format.

---

Comment: Kept reading the variable names and didn't realize they were.... OMG!!! wasted so much time on this!! shame on me.

Answer (score 1):

You are printing out the value of the decimal (i.e. `moneyConversion`), not the string representation of it (`moneyConversionString`).

Comment: Seriously, sometimes I need to take a break.